# Why is mxCreateNumericMatrix maximum size smaller than system maximum array size?

Tags: arrays, matlab, mex

I am trying to create a matrix in a MEX function. The following works:

```
uint64_t N;
N = 2147483647; // N = 2*2^30 -1
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(N,1,mxUINT8_CLASS,mxREAL);
```

However, I am unable to create an array that is this size:

```
uint64_t N;
N = 2147483648; // N = 2*2^30
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(N,1,mxUINT8_CLASS,mxREAL);
```

The preceding code throws the error:

```
maximum variable size allowed by the function exceeded
```

Which is confusing since my system (64-bit Linux running 64-bit Matlab 2010b) tells me the maximum array size is, in fact, very large.

```
[~,M] = computer
M = 
    281474976710655 % 2^48 -1 for those of you keeping track
```

Furthermore, from the command line, I am able to create very large arrays, and have been quite happily for some time, with calls like the following:

```
a = zeros(16*2^30,1,'uint8');
disp(uint64(numel(a)))
17179869184
```

My question is, why am I not able to create arrays in my mex function that I am clearly able to create from the command line, or from other *.m functions?

Thank you.

P.S. - I have also asked this question in the Mathworks forum. I figured I'd cast as large a net as possible. If it is answered there first, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in the compiler options. By default, Matlab limits the size to 2^31-1. To increase the size, the following option must be included in your mex compile command.

```
mex -largeArrayDims myFunction.c
```

Comment: I don't know why this hasn't been made the default for 64-bit MATLAB installations yet.